# Asus Eye Care switcher is not automatically working as expected

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop

So not sure if you know this [Asus Eye Care](https://www.asus.com/Microsite/display/eye_care_technology/) switcher program, but let me show you a picture.

[image: Asus Eye Care]

So thats the program, what it does is it switches to some kind of yellow background to a less blue screeny screen.

Before the Windows 10 update, everytime I restart my computer it won't take the Asus Eyecare effect for an amount of minutes, that is normal.

But now after the Windows 10 update, when I restart I have to manually click that program two times. One time because it switches first yellow, then I have to click it again so it switches to less blue.

When I start a game it auto disables it, which is normal. When I close a game it also reenables it, but then... it goes away and I have to manually activate it again.

How do you control that thing?

Once I plugged in my USB Stick and then the eye care disabled itself and the blue screen light came up again. I had to reenable eye care switcher and set it to off, so I have that what I want again.

I think these popups cause the issue

[image: Popup]

but maybe only when I plug the usb device inside apperantly.

Comment: Windows 10 has this feature built in now, no need for extra software. I'd suggest trying this out and seeing if it works for you. Open your Settings and search for "Night Light".

Comment: @JakeGould Nope, because I don't know if I lose my settings when I uninstall it do you know what I mean? I don't want to uninstall it and reinstall it and then lose all stuff that was good before.

I need to know when I install it back that it will be good like before.